# Django editing and deleting, using Generic editing views or making functions in views.

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add functionalities to edit and delete post. 
I googled around and it seems like there are two options, creating functions  like in here, [How do I edit and delete data in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311188/how-do-i-edit-and-delete-data-in-django) or just using generic editing views like here: [Create, Update and Delete in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628358/create-update-and-delete-in-django) I personally want to use generic editing views, but it's kinda harder  to understand than just creating functions. If you can help me using generic editing views, I would be appreciated.

```
def post(request, slug):
    single_post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    single_post.views += 1  # increment the number of views
    single_post.save()      # and save it
    t = loader.get_template('main/post.html')
    context_dict = {
        'single_post': single_post,
    }
    c = Context(context_dict)
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
def add_post(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():  # is the form valid?
            form.save(commit=True)  # yes? save to database
            return redirect(index)
        else:
            print form.errors  # no? display errors to end user
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render_to_response('main/add_post.html', {'form': form}, context)




class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = models.TextField()
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    ups = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    down = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = uuslug(self.title, instance=self, max_length=100)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title       



class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="plz enter")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'image', 'views', 'category']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of each

On `views.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from .models import *
from .forms import *

class PostCreateView(CreateView):
   model = Post
   form_class = PostForm
   template_name = 'form.html'

   def form_valid(self, form):
      self.object = form.save(commit=False)
      # any manual settings go here
      self.object.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())

   @method_decorator(login_required)
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      return super(PostCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
   model = Post
   form_class = PostForm
   template_name = 'form.html'

   def form_valid(self, form):
      self.object = form.save(commit=False)
      # Any manual settings go here
      self.object.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())

   @method_decorator(login_required)
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     return super(PostUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class PostDeleteView(DeleteView):
   model = Post

   def get_success_url(self):
      return reverse('post-index')  # Or whatever you need

   @method_decorator(login_required)
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      return super(PostDeleteView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

on the `urls.py`, you need something like

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from .views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^add/$', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-add'),
   url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-edit'),
   url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
)
```

You will need a post_confirm_delete.html template like:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
   <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ object }}"?</p>
   <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
</form>
```

Hope that is what you were looking for.

Here is a full tutorial on the topic

http://www.onespacemedia.com/news/2014/feb/5/getting-started-generic-class-based-views-django/

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I've been waiting for it so long ^^, I'm doing my first project in django. the code you posted, that belongs to models.py right?

Comment: No, the code here belongs to views.py. I am relying on the forms you have above which should go in forms.py I will edit the reply with the urls

Comment: I'm sorry I'm having a little bit hard time understanding this, so I should delete my add_post function in views.py then general editing views package will do all the work?

Comment: Yes, you asked how to do the same using Class based views, so my examples show you how to do an add, an edit and a delete. You should still check. You may want to review the overview on class base views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/

Comment: Also When I implement those codes it gives me, name 'method_decorator' is not defined. I googled it but couldnt find the answer

Comment: `django method_decorator` found this for me, but I just added it to my answer. I cannot give you perfectly working code as I am copy and pasting from my own code.  But just google (always using 'django .....') and you should find whatever includes I am missing

Comment: Yeah...I googled it but this error won't be fixed. now I'm getting name 'PostCreateView' is not defined, will you please take a look at my git repository?I've been working on this for like 4hours now https://github.com/lip365/ebagu0.2

Comment: You may want to take a quick course on Python as you are going to have a hard time with django if you don't know Python. If PostCreateViee is defined on views.py, the. You need 'from .views import *' on your urls.py

Comment: I added a bunch of includes to see if that works. There are probably a bunch of tutorials on the web for you to understand Django. You asked for example of code, and I gave you that. But I cannot give you a full working project. This assumes you know the basics of Django

Comment: yeah..i appreciate helping me:)..I still want to use add_post method, and just want edit and delete functionality through generic editing. but thing is I did everything you helped me to, then this page http://127.0.0.1:8000/aaa/edit/ should show up right?(aaa)being my post name. but it gives me Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET

Comment: i fixied it with changing url  to     url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/edit/$', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-edit'),
but now it gives me template doesn't exist form.html

Comment: That's correct because in my example, I am using 'pk' in the URL which represent the record ID ( as in /post/5/edit ). If you want to use the slug, then you will need to change the regexp in the URL. Start with simple IDs. I was also assuming you had a global urls.py which includes your post app urls as recommended by django docs. It also does not make sense to use the add in one style and the edit and delete in a different style. Either use class based views everywhere or nowhere.

Comment: do you know any default template I can use?

Comment: Sorry, that's a complete different question. If I answered this one, please accept it

Comment: then if I want to use add_function, how should I delete or edit?

Comment: Ok, thank you so much I'm almost done. (this is still what I asked ^^=> what should I do for PostDeleteView, this one doesn't need template but when I run the code it shows TemplateDoesNotExist at /aaa/delete/

main/post_confirm_delete.html

Comment: This time it gave NameError at /aaa/delete/, global name 'reverse' is not defined. So I googled it and thought the answer is to put from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse but it still gives me same error....

Comment: I am fairly sure it gave you another error. But just replace with `return "/"`.

Comment: it gives me global name 'reverse' is not defined, replace what with return "/"? I tried replacing with       return reverse('post-index')  #but same error

Comment: now I know how to do crud, programming is so much better with you!

Comment: Yes of course,can you also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34059010/image-scraping-with-beautifulsoup-in-django I posted this too but no answer :(((